# How can I make a ComboBox non-editable in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to have a "select-only" `ComboBox` that provides a list of items for the user to select from. Typing should be disabled in the text portion of the `ComboBox` control.

My initial googling of this turned up an overly complex, misguided suggestion to capture the `KeyPress` event.

Answer (score 427, accepted):

To make the text portion of a ComboBox non-editable, set the DropDownStyle property to "DropDownList".  The ComboBox is now essentially select-only for the user. You can do this in the Visual Studio designer, or in C# like this:

```
stateComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Link to the documentation for the [ComboBox DropDownStyle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind doing this means you can no longer update the `Text` property programmically, was using it to show a default message using `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Comment: Is there a way to do this through the GUI for Visual C# without having to edit it in the code?  Seems like a 'default value' would be a normal thing to want set up

Comment: How do I avoid the gray appearance?

Comment: @AndersLindén set the property FlatStyle to Flat.

Comment: @Xam Then where does the border go? When googling a bit, it seems I have to do the drawing myself to have it look acceptable.

Comment: @AndersLindén yeah, if you don't like the default look of flat style, then the only solution is to owner draw the ComboBox.

Comment: @Xam Do you know of some alternative component library that will not require owner drawing to look great?

Comment: @AndersLindén you could try Devexpress or Telerik. Another alternative is to keep the `FlatStyle` to `Standard` and use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789751/8781554) to change the default gray appareance of the `DropDownList` style.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think you should never need to draw in a component that should be ready to use as it is.

Answer (score 76):

To add a Visual Studio GUI reference, you can find the `DropDownStyle` options under the Properties of the selected ComboBox:

[image]

Which will automatically add the line mentioned in the first answer to the Form.Designer.cs `InitializeComponent()`, like so:

```
this.comboBoxBatch.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Answer (score 33):

Stay on your ComboBox and search the DropDropStyle property from the properties window and then choose *DropDownList*.

Answer (score 4):

**Before**

[image]

### **Method1**

[image]

### **Method2**

```
cmb_type.DropDownStyle=ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```cs
COMBOBOXID.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Answer (score 1):

To continue displaying data in the input after selecting, do so:

```
VB.NET
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
End Sub



C#
Private void ComboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Obligatory to point out: the C# one will not compile - `Private` must be all lowercase, i.e. `private`.

Answer (score 0):

for winforms .NET change DropDownStyle to DropDownList from Combobox property