# Readonly ComboBox in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, readonly

I'm writing a GUI in C#, Visual Studio 2008, using the Designer and WinForms.  I've got a ComboBox control, and I'd like it to only allow to select from the provided options and not to accept a user-entered string.  It doesn't appear to have a ReadOnly property, and disabling it hinders the readability of the control (as well as disallowing user-selection).

Comment: The DropDownStyle property was what I was looking for.  Can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a ComboBox non-editable in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85702/how-can-i-make-a-combobox-non-editable-in-net)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Set DropDownStyle to "DropDownList"

Comment: But then you can not programatically manipulate the combobox.

Answer (score 11):

Set the ComboBox.DropDownStyle property to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList.

Answer (score 4):

Use code similar to the following to set the allowed options and only those options.

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four"});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to go about it.

```
private void combobox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DropDownListbox