# Winforms Combobox - do not allow user to edit items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

This is probably something simple. The winforms combobox items by default can be edited by the user, how to disable this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Readonly ComboBox in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162936/readonly-combobox-in-winforms)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a ComboBox non-editable in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85702/how-can-i-make-a-combobox-non-editable-in-net)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Set DropDownStyle = DropDownList.

Comment: These answers should be rejected. Simply setting the comboxbox to a DropDownStyle of "DropDownList" takes away the ability of the user to start typing and filtering the list based on user input. This is extremely helpful for large lists.

Comment: @DavidP it is a working solution and it should not be rejected based on just that aspect. Your comment is valuable though.

Answer (score 14):

Set the ComboBox.DropDownStyle to [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx).

```
ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

> Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and
>   that the text portion is not editable. This means that the user cannot
>   enter a new value. Only values already in the list can be selected.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `ComboBox` style to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the DropDownStyle property to DropDownList. Style of Simple makes it like a listbox, Combobox is what you are seeing allowing editing, and DropDownList only allows user to select.

Answer (score 1):

two Method that help you Stop User to not Edit DropDownList:

A. using Programming code:

DropDownListName.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;\

B. using Design properties of Visual Studio

Set  DropDownStyle = DropDownList.

I hope this well help you.