# C# how can I make a listbox dropdown like a combobox does?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make a listbox dropdown like a combobox?

Or is it possible to configure a combobox so that the user can't add values but rather only select from the available list of values?

This is for a desktop application.

Comment: EDIT: What Nelson said. Also, by default, a user will only be able to select items from a ComboBox.

Comment: That's true, both WinForms and WPF have a ComboBox control.

Comment: @oltman, the default in WinForms is to allow input of any text as well as selecting from the list.

Comment: @ChrisF I guess I can only speak to WPF. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @oltman - I had to double check! It would have helped in the post had been tagged "winforms".

Comment: Guys I didn't know the difference between winforms and WPF. (I'm a SQL Server developer trying to build out my skill set).  But thanks to my stackoverflow friends I know the difference now. Thanks

Comment: +1 for an excellent question leading to a good solution of using ComboBox instead of ListBox by simply setting its `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a ComboBox non-editable in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85702/how-can-i-make-a-combobox-non-editable-in-net)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ComboBox control has a DropDownStyle property used to set this. Set it to DropDownList.

Answer (score 8):

Set the [DropDownStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx) to [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx):

> Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and that the text portion is not editable. This means that the user cannot enter a new value. Only values already in the list can be selected. The list displays only if AutoCompleteMode is Suggest or SuggestAppend.

like:

```
DropDownStyle = DropDownList;
```

Comment: +1 for me too for quoting *"that the text portion is not editable"*.

Answer (score 4):

Set the ComboBox.DropDownStyle property to DropDownList - that should give you the behaviour you need