# Combobox appearance

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, combobox

Can I change the appearance of a Winforms ComboBox so that a Combobox with `DropDownStyle = DropDownList` looks more like one that is `DropDownStyle = DropDown`.  The functional difference between them is that the former doesn't allow for user entered values, the problem is that it's default color scheme looks grayed out and doesn't match with textboxes on the same dialog.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can get `DropDown` appearance from `DropDownList` style by changing `DrawMode` property to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` and handling item painting by yourself (thankfully, that's easy). Sample class, implementing this idea:

```
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    public ComboBoxEx()
    {
        base.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        base.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if(e.State == DrawItemState.Focus)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        var index = e.Index;
        if(index < 0 || index >= Items.Count) return;
        var item = Items[index];
        string text = (item == null)?"(null)":item.ToString();
        using(var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is that something you wrote from scratch or pulled from the framework using reflection?

Comment: It's written from scratch. In fact, this behavior is not really expected. Some time ago I needed to implement a combo box with customized item painting and noticed that changing `DrawMode` property also affects control style, forcing it to `DropDown`.

Comment: @max this is simple and at the same time too professional ! Amazing and Thank you ! :D +1000

Answer (score 2):

You could try to change the `FlatStyle` property and see if you get something more to your liking.  If you really want it to look like it does with `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDown`, you could set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDown` and eat the `KeyPress` event:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Still, I would probably not do this as the appearance of the `ComboBox` is a visual cue to the user indicating whether they should be able to type in the text area or not.

Comment: At least in win7 that only changes the border.  The interior of the control remains a gray gradient similar to the form background.  IIRC in XP the difference between the two drop styles was much less dramatic.