# How to add padding between items in a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, listbox, padding

I'm wondering if there's a way to add padding between my line items. It's a form intended to be used on a tablet, and space between each one would make it easier to select different items.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an `ItemHeight` property.

You have to change `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawFixed` to use custom `ItemHeight`.

When you use `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` you have to paint/draw items "manually".

Here is an example: [Combobox appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789596/combobox-appearance)

Code from link above (written/provided by [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356716/max)):

```
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    public ComboBoxEx()
    {
        base.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        base.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if(e.State == DrawItemState.Focus)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        var index = e.Index;
        if(index < 0 || index >= Items.Count) return;
        var item = Items[index];
        string text = (item == null)?"(null)":item.ToString();
        using(var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
}
```