# How to add spaces between items in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Is there a way to add spaces between listbox items on Windows Form ?

I've searched for it a lot and didn't find a solution.

I mean a something like:

```
listBox1.ColumnSpace = Value;
```

like this image:

[image]

**Without adding a new item to make the space.**

Thanks for helping

Comment: what do you mean by space? height of listbox item?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298701/how-to-add-padding-between-items-in-a-listbox) if winforms, try Margin or Padding if WPF. But please clarify your question.

Comment: it's on Windows Forms

Comment: Use a ListView instead! Here you can add an imagelist and set the imageheight to your liking. you do not need to actually assign images.  The ListBox's ItemHeight is derived from the fontSize, so you can't change it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you need to owner-draw the item. You have to change `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawFixed` to use custom `ItemHeight`. Then, you need to paint the items yourself. Assign a handler to the `DrawItem` event to do so.

Comment: Is there a away to Edit ItemHeight without drawing ?

Comment: Not per the documentation, no. You may be able to change the `ItemHeight`, but it won't affect the display. To do that you need to owner-draw.

Comment: But It's very hard to draw when you have 28 listboxes.

Comment: You can assign the same handler to all the list boxes if you just want the item height to be different. The drawing code could be the same for all of them

Comment: So there is no way to add space on windows form ?

Comment: Wrong. There is a way. I outlined it above. The correct question is: *So there is no way **that I like** to add space on windows form*? :-)

Comment: :D the problem is that I need to have a delete option too. I'm tring to fing the easiest way to do the program.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question and make sure to add also what exactly you want to achieve. That would help you get better answers.

Comment: Do you know how can I check if an Item on a specific listbox was selected?

Comment: Yes, but that would be part of another question :-D

Comment: Just answer shortly please

Comment: Look at the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` properties.

Answer (score 0):

With `WPF` you can use padding on the items, such as:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Padding = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10), Content = "Item 1" });
listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Padding = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10), Content = "Item 2" });
listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Padding = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10), Content = "Item 3" });
```

Or use a style to set this on all items.

Comment: Would work if you had an item template - otherwise it would only add space between the border of the list box and the items, but not the items themselves, right?

Comment: Yes Thorsten, I should have said set the padding on the items; I have editted my answer.

Comment: But I can't find **Padding**

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you have specified WinForms - this answer is valid for WPF