# Change ListBox item spacing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I have this interface:

[image]

What I want to do is align or space the names on the left that are in a `ListBox` with the grid on the right so that each name is inline with each grid row.

I did try this:

```
lstNames.ItemHeight = 15;
```

But this does not effect it. Note: My `listbox` is created dynamically and populated using a database.

Any Tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: `Tacit` You have to change DrawMode property to OwnerDrawFixed to use custom ItemHeight.

When you use DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed you have to paint/draw items "manually".

Comment: @DJ KRAZE beat me to it. I was typing the same thing up.

Comment: It would be easier to use a DataGridView for all of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawFixed` to use custom `ItemHeight`.

When you use `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` you have to `paint/draw items "manually".`

Referenced from `Max` of this `Stackoverflow` posting [Combobox appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789596/combobox-appearance)

```
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    public ComboBoxEx()
    {
        base.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        base.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if(e.State == DrawItemState.Focus)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        var index = e.Index;
        if(index < 0 || index >= Items.Count) return;
        var item = Items[index];
        string text = (item == null)?"(null)":item.ToString();
        using(var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave you an example not that this was referenced from Max I could have added the link but the code sample would be easier for you to see opposed to navigating to numerous links

Comment: Ok Thanks it looks way too much but ill give it ago

Comment: not all things in coding are easy as one line sometimes the simple things take a bit of work as well Tacit