# Adding a Label on WinForms ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a "Clear" button on the WinForms ComboBox. So I created a custom control that inherits from ComboBox and added a Label to it. Here's the entire code:

```
public class ComboBoxClear : ComboBox
{
    private readonly Label lblClear;

    public ComboBoxClear()
    {
        lblClear = new Label
        {
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
            AutoSize = true,
            Text = "✖",
            ForeColor = Color.Gray,
            Visible = false,
            Font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.Size),
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
        };

        Controls.Add(lblClear);
        lblClear.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            lblClear.Visible = false;
            SelectedIndex = -1;
        };

        lblClear.BringToFront();
        SetLocation();
    }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public bool ShowClearButton { get; set; } = true;

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        lblClear.Visible = ShowClearButton && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text);
    }

    protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFontChanged(e);
        lblClear.Font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.Size);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        SetLocation();
    }

    private void SetLocation() =>
        lblClear.Location = new Point(Width - (lblClear.Width * 2), ((Height - lblClear.Height) / 2) - 3);
}
```

However, this does not work as expected. When I type, the label shows for a moment then goes hidden if I type again or move the mouse. Interestingly when I hover the mouse over it, the cursor changes but it's like the intersection of the label and the ComboBox is cleared.

I tried overriding the "OnPaint" or handling "Paint" event, none seem to be triggered.

Comment: Do you want `Clear` to appear when there is no user selection and when a selection is made show the selection?

Comment: ComboBox displays the selected text in a textbox control.  It is very notorious for breaking all the rules of painting.  Goes back to Win2 when it had to run on very anemic hardware, it draws itself without relying on the Paint event.  With the unpleasant side-effect you observed.  Gazillions of hacks prevented them from fixing its behavior, you can't change the way it works.  At best you might consider adding the label control to the parent of the combobox.  Yuck.

Comment: @HansPassant That is definitely interesting to know. I would've loved to have a simple solution to this but seems like unfortunately, I have to create a User Control with a ComboBox and a label. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post, you mention that an override to `OnPaint` won't get hit. That particular issue can be overcome by having `ClearComboBox` implement `IMessageFilter` and installing a hook for the `WM_PAINT` message. Nevertheless, even after PInvoking all over myself to try and `CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL`, the only way I could get this to work reliably (for example, in a challenging environment like a `FlowLayoutControl`) is to have the `ComboBoxClear` and the `_lblClear` share a deterministic parent `Control` (but it doesn't need to be a `UserControl` specifically) at which point the hook seems unnecessary once `_lblClear` is brought to the front.

[image: flow-layout-panel]

Your comment made it sound like you've already covered this ground but here's my code anyway.

---

```
public class ComboBoxClearControl : Control
{
    public ComboBoxClearControl()
    {
        _comboBoxClear = new ComboBoxClear();
        _comboBoxClear.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => Height = _comboBoxClear.Height;
        Controls.Add(_comboBoxClear);
    }
    private ComboBoxClear _comboBoxClear;
    public static implicit operator ComboBox(ComboBoxClearControl comboBoxClearUserControl) =>
        comboBoxClearUserControl._comboBoxClear;
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        _comboBoxClear.Width = Width;   // Width of C goes to CB
        Height = _comboBoxClear.Height; // Height of CB goes to C
    }
    public class ComboBoxClear : ComboBox, IMessageFilter
    {
        public ComboBoxClear() => Margin = new Padding(); 

        const int CB_DROP_HANDLE_WIDTH = 26;
        bool _isHandleInitialized = false;
        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            if (!(DesignMode || _isHandleInitialized))
            {
                _isHandleInitialized = true;
                _lblClear.Size = new Size(Height - 6, Height - 4);
                _lblClear.Location =
                    new Point(
                        Location.X + Width - _lblClear.Width - CB_DROP_HANDLE_WIDTH,
                        Location.Y + 2
                );
                Parent.Controls.Add(_lblClear);
                _lblClear.BringToFront();
                _lblClear.Click += (sender, e) => Text = String.Empty;
                TextChanged += (sender, e) => _lblClear.Visible = Text.Any();
                Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
            }
        }
        private Label _lblClear = new Label
        {
            BackColor = SystemColors.Window,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            Text = "✖",
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Font = new Font("Tahoma", 6),
            Padding = new Padding(),
            Margin = new Padding(),
            Visible = false,
        };
        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
            { } // Paint something if needed
            return false;
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            if (disposing)
            {
                Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
            }
        }
        const int WM_PAINT = 0x000f;
    }
}
```

---

**TESTBENCH**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var comboBoxClearUserControl = new ComboBoxClearControl
            {
                Width = 250,
            };
            ComboBox comboBox = comboBoxClearUserControl;
            comboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
            comboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                "Apple",
                "Orange",
                "Banana"});
            comboBox.Font = new Font(comboBox.Font.FontFamily, 16F);
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(comboBoxClearUserControl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh! I did try that but I tired it at the constructor level which returned `Parent` to be `null` so I just moved those lines to the `OnHandleCreated` and everything worked. Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your issue, but you are instantiating a label, adding it to your controls, setting a click event on it, and bringing it to the front ***inside*** your combo box constructor, and that ***could*** be the problem.

I'm not sure if a `Form.Label` can be instantiated and used from a `Form.ComboBox` or not, and I'm not sure if you want to use some parent `Label` property of combo box and add it to some parent `Controls` property of combo box, or if you want to use `Form.Label`, but unless you want your label to somehow be part of your combo box, then you should put your label somewhere next to your combo box as part of your `Form` and try setting up your label within your form instead of your combo box constructor. For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label .Location = new Point(50, 50);
        label .AutoSize = true;
        label .Text = "Whatever";
  
        this.Controls.Add(label );
  
        ComboBox mybox = new ComboBox();
        mybox.Location = new Point(50, 100);
        mybox.Size = new Size(200, 25);
        mybox.Items.Add("beep");
        mybox.Items.Add("bop");
        mybox.Items.Add("boop");
        mybox.Items.Add("bleep");
        mybox.Items.Add("blop");
  
        this.Controls.Add(mybox);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OnPaint method is not triggered for a combo box like it is for other forms controls because this particular control handles painting differently. You may be able to achieve what you are trying to by overriding the OnDrawItem method instead.  Take a look at this answer which may give you some inspiration! [Combobox appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789596/combobox-appearance)