# How can I prevent users from entering data into DataGridViewComboBoxCells?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a project that uses a number of DataGridView controls.  Most of the cells are of the  DataGridViewTextBoxCell persuasion.  I declare my controls like so:

```
Dim MyCell as DataGridViewCell
```

Later I specify whether they are DataGridViewTextBoxControls or DataGridViewComboBoxCells like so:

```
MyCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell   ...or...
MyCell = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
```

None of the places in my code require the ability for the users to enter their own values in the Combo Boxes.  That is, they are either hard-coded or the values are gathered from other data within the application.

Currently, users can highlight a combo box control defined as shown above and begin typing anything they like.  For example, I have one combo box that offers the user a selection of integers between 1 and 9.  I can highlight the combo box cell and enter "Hello, World!" if I'd like.

What does it take to disable this ability?  I'm sure there's a property, but I have yet to find it.  I have searched the Internet, and have found only the ability to have user-entered values added to the list and a stream of data-binding tutorials.

Thank you in advance!
C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85702/how-can-i-make-a-combobox-non-editable-in-net)

**EDIT**

I probably should have put more information up, but I'm tired and feeling a little sick so I felt like being lazy ... but no you have to ruin my laziness and force me to type some more. (LOL just joking).

Essentially the comboxbox that you see in a comboboxcell is acutally a combobox control (Tired = Bad Engrish).

From what I can recall, you should be able to get at the control used in the cell by using the EditingControlShowing event of the datagridview. Once there you just set the dropdownstyle.

Like:

```
Private Sub datagridview_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)

    Dim c As ComboBox = e.Control

    If Not c Is Nothing Then

        c.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If this was a straight-up ComboBox control, and not a DataGridViewComboBoxCell, this would work fine.  Unless there's a magic trick to DataGridViewComboBoxCells that allow them to use this property, and I haven't found it yet.