# How to lock combobox so that the text and items cannot be modified/delete/erased?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible lock the combobox so that the text can not be deleted/erased or modified. And make only choose the items? Thank you in advance. Hope is it possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a ComboBox non-editable in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85702/how-can-i-make-a-combobox-non-editable-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

Set the "DropDownStyle" property of the combobox to **DropDownList**. 
This will allow only items in the list to be selected and will not allow any user input:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Simply set the `ComboBox.Enabled` to `False` - that way they can't change the values!

**Option 2**

Otherwise, use the dropDownStyle:

make `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList` instead of `DropDown`

**For more information**

Read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9952/ComboBox-with-read-only-behavior) (yes, it's written in c#, but the properties are the same!)

[image: The Different Styles]

the above image displays this quite well.

**EDIT**

There is also a question previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85702/how-can-i-make-a-combobox-non-editable-in-net) that asked a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`ComboBox.DropDownStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`.